# Why i can't specify little endian in numpy dtype

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I tried to define a little endian datatype of 2 Bytes in numpy by:

```
import numpy as np


dt = np.dtype('<u2')  # little endian unsigned int
```

But if i check the byteorder of this datatype by:

```
print(dt.byteorder)
```

It gives me: "=" not "<"

"=" means in that case "hardware default"

Is "little endian" the hardware default or whats the issue here?

Comment: You most likely answered your own question. Not sure where youd buy a big-endian machine today. Try creating a big endian type instead, and see if that gives a different result. Whenever I have had to use expliclt-endian code in numpy, it always worked exactly as expected.

Comment: little-endian is not a general hardware default but it is the native endianness on your specific processor. Most mainstream processors (x86-64) are little-endian. Some support both little-endian (called bi-endian) and big endian like ARM and PowerPC although in practice the software stack tends to use the little-endian format for sake of compatibility. Numpy automatically convert the little-endianness to native-endianness if your processor (or the software stack for bi-endian processors) is little-endian and do the opposite for big-endianness.